# Is there a way to limit the memory consumed by a process on startup

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I want to wrap up my process inside a script `./start.sh` where it calls "`./real_process`", and let linux automatically kill real_process when it takes more than 8G of memory.

I don't want this restriction for "all processes". Just that particular one. and I want to do it at startup.

Comment: Read the bash man pages about [ulimit internal command](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)

Comment: @Jdamian I don't want this restriction for "all processes". Just that particular one. and I want to do it at startup.

Comment: Where have you read that the `ulimit` command applies to **all processes**? Read carelfully Jeremy Gurr's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use ulimit at the start of your script:

```
ulimit -m 8000000
```

or if that is unavailable for some reason, fork your real_process into the background and use the remainder of your script to check periodically if it's memory usage has exceeded the 8G, and terminate.

```
while true; do
    # check memory usage of process
    # kill process if too high
    sleep 60
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set it up to constantly grab memory usage from /proc/$pid/smap. Once its over your 8GB max, kill the process.

Get the pid using `ps -e| grep [your_process_name]`. Grab memory usage with `$value='/proc/$pid/smap'` and compare `$value` to whatever value you need to determine if it is less than 8GB. Use `Kill` command to kill process. Throw this in a loop.